# using multiple google compute engine filters

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying to use multiple compute engine filters in list* calls, for example:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<PROJECT>/regions/us-east1/addresses?filter=(status+eq+RESERVED)+(address+eq+%22<IP>%22)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

All such calls seem to return  "Invalid value for field 'filter'", though the documentation states:

> The Beta API also supports filtering on multiple expressions by
>   providing each separate expression within parentheses. For example,
>   (scheduling.automaticRestart eq true) (zone eq us-central1-f).
>   Multiple expressions are treated as AND expressions, meaning that
>   resources must match all expressions to pass the filters.

Is this a known issue, or am I going about this incorrectly?